# When creating an image, packer throws errors

Tags: amazon-ec2, devops

The packer file looks like this:

```
{
    "variables": {
        "name": "packer",
        "source_ami": "ami-0d527b8c289b4af7f",
        "access_key": "",
        "secret_key": "",
        "region": "eu-central-1"
    },
    "builders": [
        {
            "type": "amazon-ebs",
            "access_key": "{{user `access_key`}}",
            "secret_key": "{{user `secret_key`}}",
            "ami_name": "{{user `name`}}",
            "region": "{{user `region`}}",
            "source_ami": "{{user `source_ami`}}",
            "instance_type": "t2.micro",
            "communicator": "ssh",
            "ssh_username": "ubuntu",
            "run_tags": {
                "Name": "reddit"
            }
        }
    ],
    "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "script": "/home/ansibleclient/devops/scripts/reddit_scripts/bash/install_ruby.sh",
            "execute_command": "sudo {{.Path}}"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "script": "/home/ansibleclient/devops/scripts/reddit_scripts/bash/install_mongodb.sh",
            "execute_command": "sudo {{.Path}}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Ruby installation file:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# Update system
add-apt-repository ppa:awstools-dev/awstools
apt-get update
# Install Ruby
apt-get install -y ruby-full ruby-bundler build-essential
```

MondoDB installation file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Mongodb
echo "y" | apt-get install mongodb

# Start MongoDB
systemctl start mongodb

# Add to autorun
systemctl enable mongodb

# Check status mongodb
systemctl status mongodb
```

When executing the "packer build" command, errors appear:

The first error appears 2 times, and I do not understand what it is connected with, it appears when using scripts.

```
==> amazon-ebs: debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
==> amazon-ebs: debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
==> amazon-ebs: debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
==> amazon-ebs: debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
==> amazon-ebs: debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
==> amazon-ebs: debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
==> amazon-ebs: dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin:
```

The second error appears when implementing the script "install_mongodb.sh "

```
 ==> amazon-ebs: Synchronizing state of mongodb.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
    ==> amazon-ebs: Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with Packer, but a Linux behavior when using non interactive shell.

Assuming you're using Ubuntu, try using `export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` before `apt` commands.
There are few other alternatives and ways to solve this (in my experience the `noninteractive` does not always work).

You can also try to add `DEBIAN_PRIORITY=critical`

So something like this for the `provision.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive;
export DEBIAN_PRIORITY=critical;
apt-get -qy clean;
apt-get -qy update;
apt-get -qy upgrade;

add-apt-repository ppa:awstools-dev/awstools
apt-get -qy update;
apt-get install -y ruby-full ruby-bundler build-essential

apt-get install -y mongodb
systemctl start mongodb
systemctl enable mongodb
systemctl status mongodb
```

Also, it's worth reading StackOverflow guidelines, it will help you to write better questions, and increase the probability of getting an answer.